# PHP search and replace regex pattern

Tags: php, regex, matching

I'm trying to get a string which matches by a regex pattern ( {$ ... } ). But I don't want the brackets and the $ sign returned.

For example

```
{$Testpath}/Testlink
```

should return

```
Testpath
```

My regex pattern looks like this at the moment:

```
^{\$.*}$
```

Comment: Why you're using `^` and `$` - is the value should be captured only if the entire containing string matches the rule?

Comment: a ^{\$(.*)} will give you a match in the match array. You don't need the last $ in your regex because it matches the end of the string but your searched value isn't at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following regex:

```
^\{\$\K[^}]*(?=\})
```

[Regex101 Demo](http://regex101.com/r/nQ2aZ8)

This expression mathces start-of-string `^` then a literal `{` then a literal `$` then it ignores those using `\K` anchor, then it matches one or more characters which aren't a `}` then it looks ahead `(?=\})` for a literal `}`.

You may not need the end-of-line anchor `$` because the text you are trying to match might not end at the end of the string and you may not need the start-of-line `^` anchor for the opposite reason, that is the pattern you are trying to match may not be at the start of the string or line.

I think you should remove `^` and `$` and use the global modifier.